# c++ set<> of class objects. Using own comparer giving JUNK of errors from functional, xtree etc

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, set

The code in c++ is as follows:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<set>
using namespace std;

class data{
    int i;
    float f;
    char c;
public:
    bool operator()( data const& a1, data const& a2 ) const{
        return( a1.i < a2.i ||
            (!(a1.i > a2.i) && (a1.f < a2.f)) ||
            (!(a1.i > a2.i) && !(a1.f > a2.f) && (a1.c < a2.c)));
    };
    data();
    data(int i,float f,char c);
    int geti();
};

int data::geti(){
    return i;
};
data::data(int i,float f,char c){
    this->i=i;
    this->f=f;
    this->c=c;
};

int main(){
    set<data> s;
    set<data>::iterator it;
    s.insert(data(1,1.3,'a'));
    s.insert(data(2,2.3,'b'));
    s.insert(data(3,3.3,'c'));
    if((it=s.find(data(1,1.3,'a')))!=s.end())
        cout<<(*it).geti();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

This question is after suggested modifications in [C++ set Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783512/c-set-of-class-objects-using-own-comparer-giving-error-c2804-binary-oper)

On compilation it's giving JUNK of errors from ..\vc\include\functional  and  ..\vc\include\xtree

Please help me sort out errors.
Thanks.

Errors:

```
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const data'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(1372) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(142) : while compiling class template member function 'bool std::less<_Ty>::operator ()(const _Ty &,const _Ty &) const'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=data
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\set(60) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::less<_Ty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=data
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(26) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tset_traits<_Kty,_Pr,_Alloc,_Mfl>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=data,
1>            _Pr=std::less<data>,
1>            _Alloc=std::allocator<data>,
1>            _Mfl=false
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(68) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_nod<_Traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tset_traits<data,std::less<data>,std::allocator<data>,false>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(94) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_ptr<_Traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tset_traits<data,std::less<data>,std::allocator<data>,false>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xtree(112) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree_val<_Traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tset_traits<data,std::less<data>,std::allocator<data>,false>
1>        ]
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\set(69) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<_Traits>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Traits=std::_Tset_traits<data,std::less<data>,std::allocator<data>,false>
1>        ]
1>        c:\users\nitin_thokare\documents\visual studio 2005\projects\cpp\stl\ex_sets.cpp(31) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::set<_Kty>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Kty=data
1>        ]
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const data'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\string(151) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const _Elem *,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const _Elem *' from 'const data'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\string(141) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const data'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\string(131) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const data'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xutility(1880) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const data'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\utility(76) : see declaration of 'std::operator <'
1>c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\functional(143) : error C2676: binary '<' : 'const data' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **operator <** is miss, and it's conveniently written as member function, as below, or as friend operator outside the class:

```
int geti() const;

bool operator<( data const& a2 ) const {
    data const& a1 = *this;
    return( a1.i < a2.i ||
        (!(a1.i > a2.i) && (a1.f < a2.f)) ||
        (!(a1.i > a2.i) && !(a1.f > a2.f) && (a1.c < a2.c)));
};
```

also you forget the const qualifier:

```
int geti() const;
```

Comment: why is this const necessary? because I found it's working fine even without using const for geti().

Comment: It's not really necessary in your case, but without it we can't access the property where the STL interface mandates a const & . Typical case it's as free function operator<(const data& a1, const data &a2).

Answer (score 1):

Either use supply a `operator<` as the other already mentioned, or use `data` for the second template parameter of `std::set`.

See `std::set` declaration:

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class set;
```

So you would use `std::set<data,data>` as your set type. This way, your `operator()` would be used to compare the `data` objects.

Answer (score 1):

Using Boost, because I am tired of boilerplate.

```
class data {
  ...
public:
  bool operator<(data const& other) const {
    return boost::tie(this->i, this->f, this->c)
         < boost::tie(other.i, other.f, other.c);
  }


};
```

Much, much, more readable than your version.

Comment: +1 Interesting, but matching the semantic it's not really easy. I've included "boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp", and your hint compiles, but I feel the code is not equivalent.

Comment: @chac: the semantics are equivalent. Tuples are compared in lexicographical order, meaning that the two first items are compared, if not equal the result is known, otherwise it moves on to the next item, etc... I can understand that if feels strange at first, once you are used to it though, it just becomes so much easier to write this operator and, more importantly, to be sure that it works as intended (less code, less bugs).

Comment: Sure, but tracking *exactly* the boolean expression with all the *not*s, *or*s, *and*s it's beyond my brain...Of course, I'm not sure, for the very same reason, the original expression it's correct. I would had wrote it in different fashion, but you definitely show me the right way...

Answer (score 0):

`data` type does not have comparison operator `<` which is required by `std::set`. You probably meant to have

```
bool operator < ( data const& a2 ) const {
    return( i < a2.i ||
        (!(i > a2.i) && (f < a2.f)) ||
        (!(i > a2.i) && !(f > a2.f) && (c < a2.c)));
}
```

instead of that `data::operator()`.